# Global dependent field

Tags: apex, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

I have in object two field Type__c and Phase__c, both are picklists, there is a field dependency in these fields. Type__c is the controlling one and Phase__c is the dependent. I want the same exact field dependency in another object.

**Is there any way I can create a global field dependency so that I can attach it to two different objects.**

The reason why I want the same dependency is because the dependent fields have different options given a particular Type__c, for example:

```
Type__c {1,2,3}
Phase__c{A,B,C,D,E,F}
```

Dependency:

```
if Type__c = 1, then Phase__c{A,B}
if Type__c = 2, then Phase__c{B,C,E}
if Type__c = 3, then Phase__c{A,B,C,D,E,F}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately as of now Salesforce doesn't support this functionality. So you need to create two separate fields on another object and then manually make them dependent.

You can also vote this Idea: [Field dependent for global picklist](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lDPLQA2)